# Sorting CSV into a dictionary in a Class

Tags: python, class, csv, dictionary

I have been trying to create a Class that will accept a CSV file, read it and sort it into a dictionary using one of the rows as a key. Everything i can find online in relation to csv files, deals with them outside of classes.

I am trying to Open the csv file (called `books.csv`) and read each row into a private attribute of the Shelf class called `__books` that is a dictionary. The dictionary should use the ISBN as a key.

I want to get the csv file `books.csv` into the dictionary `__books{ }` and put the 4th row as a key but every time I run it, it states that the `books.csv` file isn't being read into the dictionary.

The first piece of code is:

```
class Book:

    def __init__(self, title, author, price, isbn):
        self.title = title
        self.author = author
        self.price = price
        self.isbn=isbn

    def getISBN(self):
         return self.isbn


class Shelf:

    __books={}

    def __init__(self,filename):
        f=open(filename, encoding="utf8")
        csvreader = csv.reader(f)

    for row in csvreader:
        abook=Book(row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3])
        self.__books[row[4]]=abook
```

This code will be called into another file and the corresponding code is:

```
aShelf=Shelf("books.csv")
    abook=aShelf._Shelf__books["0743482836"]
    if abook.author == "A. Goose":
        pass
    else:
        raise Exception
```

Comment: What do you mean by imported into the dictionary? How is what you have now not functioning correctly?

Comment: Sorry if it's unclear. the actual question is:  Open the csv file (called "books.csv") and read each row into a private attribute of the Shelf class called
__books that is a dictionary. The dictionary should use the ISBN as a key.                                                                                                               I want to get the csv file "books.csv" into the dictionary  __books{ } and put the 4th tow as a key but everytime i run it, it states that the "books.csv" file isn't being read into the dictionary.

Comment: I think its due to the indentation of the block starting `for row in csvreader`. If you shift that in one level then it will become part of your `__init__` method and should work.

Comment: Another thing thats unclear is that you specify isbn as the 4th argument to your `Book` constructor and pass row[3] as that value when creating the books. You then use row[4] as the `dict` key. So is it index 3 or 4 that is the isbn? If you are using it as the key to your `dict` you could if appropriate omit if from the `Book` class and avoid the data redundancy.

Comment: Sorry that's my fault, it is indented in my code and it doesn't work then. i also changed the rows slightly as it wasnt corresponding correctly to the csv file so it is now                                                                                for row in csvreader:
                abook=Book(row[1],row[2],row[4],row[5])
                self.__books[row[5]]=abook     This meakes row[1]=title, row[2]=author, row[4]=price and row[5]=isbn as it is in the csv file.

Comment: Cool. It would be great if you could edit the question to reflect this. Essentially though the issue is solved though?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with the code. Firstly, I think the `__books` should be defined as an instance variable, not a class variable. The way you have it, if you create multiple instances of `Shelf` they will share the dictionary (I don't think that is the intent).

Secondly, when you are reading files, you should use the `with` statement so that you don't leak resources. Thirdly, as some of the comments suggest, you should pass the number of the column that you want to use as a key as an argument.

And lastly, you could provide `__getitem__` to allow easier syntax when looking up books.

```
class Shelf:
    def __init__(self,filename, key_no=3):
        self._books={}
        with open(filename, encoding="utf8") as f:
            csvreader = csv.reader(f)
            for row in csvreader:
                abook = Book(*[x.strip() for x in row])
                self._books[row[key_no].strip()] = abook

    def __getitem__(self, isbn):
        return self._books[isbn]


aShelf=Shelf("books.csv")
print(aShelf._books)

abook = aShelf["0743482836"]
if abook.author == "A. Goose":
    pass
else:
    raise Exception
```

Comment: I never knew that meant a class variable +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your error is that the section that inserts into the dictionary is not indented correctly and so doesn't run when your `__init__` method is called

**Before**

```
def __init__(self,filename):
    f=open(filename, encoding="utf8")
    csvreader = csv.reader(f)

for row in csvreader:
    abook=Book(row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3])
    self.__books[row[4]]=abook
```

**After**

```
def __init__(self,filename):
    f=open(filename, encoding="utf8")
    csvreader = csv.reader(f)

    ''' indented here '''
    for row in csvreader:
        abook=Book(row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3])
        self.__books[row[4]]=abook
```

You can also eliminate the ugly index syntax in your loop by unpacking the values as a `tuple`.

**NOTE: This section is based on the OPs updated information in comments, relating to which indexes in the csv data represent which book parameters. The earlier sections are not updated.**

```
for _, title, author, price, isbn, *_ in csvreader:
    self.__books[isbn] = Book(title, author, price, isbn)
```

That should be much more readable. The only thing that isnt clear is which index is the isbn, but I'll let you figure that one out.